# Hyphenation of CamelCaseClassNames: Mix automatic and manual?

Tags: hyphenation

My text contains some long, CamelCaseClassNames which LaTeX doesn't like to hyphenate automatically. I found the `\camelhyph` macro on [projects:latexcamel](http://www.tatome.de/bliki/doku.php?id=projects%3alatexcamel) and it works perfectly for automatic hyphenation before each upper case letter.

However, I also want to allow hyphenation within some longer words in the classname. As soon as I use the `\camelhyph` macro on anything containing `\\-` it breaks down.

Can anyone fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\camelhyph}[1]{\@fterfirst\c@amelhyph#1\relax }
  \def\@fterfirst #1#2{#2#1}
  \def\c@amelhyph #1{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}\relax}{}{%  Do nothing if the end has been reached
     \ifnum`#1<91 \-#1\else#1\fi%     Check whether #1 is an uppercase letter,
                                %     if so, print \-#1, otherwise #1
    \expandafter\c@amelhyph%    %     insert \c@amelhyph again.
}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\cclass}[1]{\texttt{\camelhyph{#1}}\xspace}
\begin{document}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Curabitur vitae lectus augue. Duis vitae quam sem. 
Integer rhoncus tempor est et convallis. Ddonec orciodio, 
facilisis in portaeget,  
\cclass{MySpecialCamelCaseLooooooongwooooordClassName} 
ornare veltortor. Pellentesque sed risus sed dolor iaculis
malesuada vitae ac purus. Praesent convallis mattis faucibus.
Nulla gravida ante id sapien tincidunt nec suscipit magna placerat. 

%not working because of the additional breakmark: \-
%Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
%Curabitur vitae lectus augue. Duis vitae quam sem. 
%Integer rhoncus tempor est et convallis. Ddonec orciodio, 
%facilisis in portaeget,  
%\cclass{MySpecialCamelCaseLooooooongwooo\-oordClassName} 
%ornare veltortor. Pellentesque sed risus sed dolor iaculis
%malesuada vitae ac purus. Praesent convallis mattis faucibus.
%Nulla gravida ante id sapien tincidunt nec suscipit magna placerat. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might not be the answer you are looking for, but for those special cases you could simply use `\texttt{MySpecialCamelCaseLooooooongwooo\-oordClassName}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to test also for `\-`:

```
\def\camelhyph#1{\c@melhyph#1\relax}
\def\c@melhyph#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \ifx#1\-#1\else
      \ifnum`#1<91 \-\fi
      #1%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\c@melhyph\expandafter
    \fi
  \fi}
```

If `#1` is `\relax` we are at the end; if it's `\-` insert it and move on; if it's an uppercase letter, insert `\-`, otherwise do nothing; insert `#1` and move on.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the `\-` command into braces: `{\-}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand{\camelhyph}[1]{\@fterfirst\c@amelhyph#1\relax }
  \def\@fterfirst #1#2{#2#1}
  \def\c@amelhyph #1{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}\relax}{}{%  Do nothing if the end has been reached
     \ifnum`#1<91 \-#1\else#1\fi%     Check whether #1 is an uppercase letter,
                                %     if so, print \-#1, otherwise #1
    \expandafter\c@amelhyph%    %     insert \c@amelhyph again.
}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\cclass}[1]{\texttt{\camelhyph{#1}}\xspace}
\begin{document}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Curabitur vitae lectus augue. Duis vitae quam sem. 
Integer rhoncus tempor est et convallis. Ddonec orciodio, 
facilisis in portaeget,  
\cclass{MySpecialCamelCaseLooooooongwooo{\-}oordClassName} 
ornare veltortor. Pellentesque sed risus sed dolor iaculis
malesuada vitae ac purus. Praesent convallis mattis faucibus.
Nulla gravida ante id sapien tincidunt nec suscipit magna placerat. 

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Should have though of this one...