# Verb end of the line alignement

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

I have a problem when I use the command `\verb|detectionFinProgramme|`. I don't know how to manage LaTex to get a normal alignement at the end of the line.

[image]

Does someone have a solution ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There can't be a "normal" alignment in such cases. You probably don't want a line break inside the "detectionFinProgramme", and if you move the word to the next line you get large spaces. Make sure that you have given LaTeX every help to find a good solution (e.g. by loading microtype) and in the rest of the cases you will have to decide manually, e.g. by changing the order of the words. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull

Comment: Note that you don't need (and probably shouldn't use) `\verb` here `\texttt{detectionFinProgramme}` would be better. It would not change the linebreak though. What do you want to happen? extra white space (try adding `\sloppy` before the paragraph) or do you want to break within the word, and if so do you want a `-` at the end of the line.

Comment: If you do want hyphens see the answer already posted, if you want breaking without hyphens another solution is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use egreg's solution to [Hyphenation of CamelCaseClassNames: Mix automatic and manual?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19446/15925) as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\camelhyph#1{\c@melhyph#1\relax}
\def\c@melhyph#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else
    \ifx#1\-#1\else
      \ifnum`#1<91 \-\fi
      #1%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\c@melhyph\expandafter
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text
\texttt{\camelhyph{detectionFinProgramme}}
filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler
text filler text filler text filler text filler text filler text.

\end{document}
```